# WP Можно ли в post meta хранить динамическую переменую, а если нет - то где?

Tags: wordpress

Столкнулся с такой нетривиальной задачей в WordPress.

Имеется кастомный тип записи, для простоты назовем его `post_type=>'companies'`. Пользователи имеют возможность оставлять комментарии на страницах данного типа записи, и в этих комментариях можно оставлять два рейтинга: `rating_product` и `rating_service` (каждый от 0 до 5). На основе этих рейтингов формируется, что в среднем данный пользователь думает о продукте: `$rating=($rating_product+$rating_service)/2`. Тут всё понятно. Сохраняются в `comments_meta` .

А теперь вопрос - есть некая переменная `$full_rating` равная сумме всех значения $rating, поделенных на количество пользователей. Это значение мы отображаем в карточке каждой компании 'companies'. Как и где её отображать ?

*Проблема состоит в том, что, предположим, администратор сайта удаляет пользователя, а это означает, что всё, что этот пользователь наголосовал, должно убраться из каждой такой переменной `$full_rating` каждого такого поста вместе с его комментариями. И каким образом будет удален пользователь (или отключен) - непонятно.

Подскажите, как можно было бы решить данную задачу. В `MySQL` не силен, но первое, что навело на мысль, это некий столбец в таблице `wp_post`, который бы каким-то образом динамически хранил значение `$full_rating` возле каждого такого поста.

Comment: `это некий столбец в таблице wp_post` -- об этом сразу забудьте, модифицировать дефолтные таблицы не стоит, для всех доп данных есть `post_meta`. Как я уже и сказал, хранить значение можно в `post_meta` компании, что логично, пересчитывать это значение при добавлении/удалении комментария. Удаление пользователя отлавливаете на хук `delete_user` и тоже пересчитываете рейтинг.

Comment: ок, предположим. Тогда как бы выглядила эта переменная `$mydata`? По выставлению рейтинга компании писать в ` update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'full_rating', $mydata );` ? Сначала проверять существует ли.., а потом?

Comment: Сам `$full_rating` я бы скорее рассчитывал, а не хранил в БД. В БД я бы хранил что-то вроде `$total_rating`, это был бы рейтинг компании, но не деленный на количество отзывов. При добавлении коммента я бы сохранял `$total_rating += $rating` (`$rating` -- это тот который у Вас `$rating=($rating_product+$rating_service)/2`), а при удалении делал бы `$total_rating -= $rating` -- где `$rating` является рейтингом удаляемого комментария. А сам ретинг считал бы так `$full_rating = $total_rating / $count;` где `$count` -- `get_comment_count()` компании. Но вообще желательно потестить конечно.

Comment: Хотя `get_comment_count()` не обязательно будет равно количеству отзывов с рейтингом, наверное это нужно тоже учитывать. Сама функция возвращает [массив](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_count/#return), если что. Не знаю как у Вас это устроено, там же и просто реплаи могут быть и рейтинг обязателен для отзыва или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С метами тут лучше не связываться - потому что надо писать и comments_meta, и в user_meta, а при удалении пользователей или постов или комментариев к ним придется делать медленные выборки по мета.

Правильный путь тут - создать свою таблицу ratings с колонками post_id, comment_id, rating_type, user_id. Писать в неё при добавлении рейтинга, удалять из нее при удалении постов, комментариев, пользователей, рейтингов, читать из неё при выводе комментариев. Ну и для подсчёта статистики - тоже читать из неё.

MySQL придётся освоить, но работать будет быстро.